# How to stop DevForce blocking UI when importing from an EntityManager

Tags: c#, wpf, devforce

The design of our application requires us to have separate EntityManagers for each module within the system. To ease the communication burden with the server for common data we have implemented a global cache EntityManager that we import a set of entities that do not change through the app lifetime.

All is working well for the most part aside from when we do an import of a large set of entities. Some of our screens require us to import upwards of 5,000 entities and whilst we have our operations in an Async manner the import provided by DevForce is synchronous. During the import the UI thread is being blocked for anywhere up to 2-3 seconds and the user will think it has hung at this point because the progress indicator cannot update.

I looked at configuring the await to make it not continue on the UI thread but that hits the guard that DevForce has in place for cross thread access to an EntityManager. I know there is a property that can be set to disable this check but I am not sure if it would cause any adverse sideeffects during the import operation so I am hesitant to use it.

If there is another solution or some secret sauce I am missing I would greatly appreciate any ideas.

Many thanks

Comment: The problem is that the EntityManager isn't thread safe, which is why the import is done on the main (UI) thread.  You can disable or customize the thread check, but you're likely to run into issues when using a single EM from two threads concurrently.